# Textbox and DateTimePicker BackColor Corner Case - Is there an explanation for this?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

Add a DateTimePicker, two TextBoxes and two Buttons to a Form

Add the following code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    DateTimePicker1.Enabled = True
    TextBox1.Enabled = True
    TextBox2.Enabled = True
    TextBox1.BackColor = DateTimePicker1.BackColor
    TextBox2.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(DateTimePicker1.BackColor.A, DateTimePicker1.BackColor.R, DateTimePicker1.BackColor.G, DateTimePicker1.BackColor.B)
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    DateTimePicker1.Enabled = False
    TextBox1.Enabled = False
    TextBox2.Enabled = False
    TextBox1.BackColor = DateTimePicker1.BackColor
    TextBox2.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(DateTimePicker1.BackColor.A, DateTimePicker1.BackColor.R, DateTimePicker1.BackColor.G, DateTimePicker1.BackColor.B)
End Sub
```

In all cases the `BackColor` read back from the `DateTimePicker`, `TextBox1` and `TextBox2` has the same ARGB values

But when `Button2` is clicked, `TextBox1`'s `BackColor` **on screen** is actually F0F0F0 (from screen grab colour picker)- Is there an explanation for this?

I assume this applies to C# as well - hence the tag.

Comment: Select the DateTimePicker, look in the Properties window.  Note that BackColor is *missing*.  Not implemented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `ReadOnly` property instead of `Enabled` property to control editable behavior and assign custom `BackColor`.

Comment: Thanks yes this is a workaround, which I have already done by setting the ARGB value, but I was after an explanation of why this happens if possible.